# Configuring git difftool

Tags: git, meld, git-difftool

I'm using git 2.18.0. In `~/.gitconfig` section `[alias]` I have diff-tool alias configured like this:

```
meld = difftool -y --tool=meld
```

Alas, `git meld` produces `diff`-style results instead of launching `meld`. Moreover, spelling it out on the command line `git difftool -y --tool=meld` also produces diff-style output. On the other hand, launching `meld` from command line is successful.

Could you suggest what may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have something to the effect of the following in you .gitconfig and get rid of the alias:

```
[diff]
    tool = meld
    guitool = meld
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "meld"]
    path = /usr/bin/meld
```

Comment: Nice and useful answer. Let's mention that Windows user will have to locate and modify the path to their executable, probably along the lines of `difftool.meld.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe` (mind quoting it when setting it by command, since you might (as is the case here) have spaces in filenames.